# BigQuery does not recognize field of a subselect in a join

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery

I tried to combine id and first_time from table B with the time_record and type in table A, joining on id. but I got the error of

```
a.time_record is not a field of either table in the join
```

Any idea how I could fix it? I am pretty sure table A has such two columns. Below is the query I used.

```
select b.id, b.first_time as day0, a.time_record,a.type
from mydata.b as b
left join each
(select id 
from table_date_range(mydata.b, timestamp("2016-01-20"),timestamp("2016-02-03")) 
group by id) 
as a
on a.id = b.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Your subselect `a` does not have the field `time_record`. Try adding it to the subselect. (Same for `a.type`.)

Comment: Yea I just found that.. Thank you so much!